# min-height not working as expected

Tags: html, css, height

Given the following structure, I need level2 have a `min-height` without changing the structure. Further, I am not able to move the `overflow: hidden` to a different `class` (the example is simplified, it would affect a lot of other things). It works with `px`, but not with `%`. All other css properties can be changed.

I am aware of vh, which works exactly like it should. But I would love a solution with CSS2.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8uj75e5/1/)

#### HTML:

```
<div id="level1">
    <div id="level2">
        <div id="heighter"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- body and html: height 100%
- level 1: min-height 100%, overflow hidden
- level 2: min-height 100%
- heighter: height 200px

**Edit: More informations about the overflow:hidden**

I am using this for a offcanvas navigation. This is a place where I can't use max-width (right?). If I replace the overflow with the max-width, the layout gets recalculated and after that I am able to scroll the level2 on the x-axis (left and right). Same problem as [here](http://callmenick.com/tutorial-demos/slide-push-menus/) (click on Push-Menu-Left and then you are able to scroll the x-axis). What I am trying right now is preventing the x-axis scrolling and being able to use the min-height: 100% corretly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to calculate `min-height`, `div#level2` needs to refer to the `height` definition of its parent. In your code, `div#level1` does not have a specified `height`. You an specify one like so:

```
#level1 {
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* This has to be here */
    background-color: red;
}
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b8uj75e5/2/)

### EDIT:

Explicitly setting `height` on `div#level1` (rather than setting `min-height`), you no longer need the `overflow:hidden` definition. Removing that allows the page to scroll when `div#heighter` expands beyond the browser's height.

(You mentioned that you need the `overflow:hidden` for other reasons. If possible, please edit your question to describe those reasons a bit more.)

```
#level1 {
    height:100%;
    background-color: red;
}

#level2 {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: lightseagreen;
}

#heighter {
    height: 2000px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px dashed black;
}
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b8uj75e5/6/)

Comment: Thanks. This was my approach too, but if the "heightener" exeeds the 100%, scrolling is disabled because of the level1-overflow-hidden. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/b8uj75e5/4/.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I edited my question with the informations you asked for. Let me know if I have to clarify something further.

Comment: Perhaps [`overflow-x:hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) would be useful.

Comment: I tested a whole bunch of different approaches today. Since none of them worked fully, I will now try to redesign the whole structure (as little as possible). I marked this answer as the correct one in  hope that it will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/b8uj75e5/3/

```
#level2 {
    min-height: 1000px; /* Working */
    min-height: 100%; /* Not working */
    background-color: lightseagreen;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

IT LIVES.

I just messed around until it worked.

Comment: Thanks. Same problem as on showdevs answer: If the "heightener" exeeds the 100%, scrolling is disabled because of the level1-overflow-hidden. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/b8uj75e5/5/.